# Parse comma-separated values in vb

Tags: vb.net, parsing

I am having arduino and getting data serially in comma-separated values. Now I want to segregate data and put into text box, my question How can parse data in Vb data displayed on text box for every 1s

```
int Count1;
int Count2;
int Count3;
int Count4;
int Count5;
float Sensor_Out1;
float Sensor_Out2;
float Sensor_Out3;
float Sensor_Out4;
float Sensor_Out5;

void TakeReading()
{
  Count1 = analogRead(A1);
  Count2=analogRead(A2);
  Count3=analogRead(A3);
  Count4=analogRead(A4);
  Count5=analogRead(A5);
  Sensor_Out1= 0.0336666666667*Count1 - 17.10;
  Sensor_Out2= 0.0336666666667*Count2 - 17.10;
  Sensor_Out3= 0.0336666666667*Count3 - 17.10;
  Sensor_Out4 = 0.0336666666667*Count4 - 17.10;
  Sensor_Out5= 0.0336666666667*Count5 - 17.10;
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  TakeReading();
  Serial.print(Sensor_Out1); 
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Sensor_Out2); 
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Sensor_Out3); 
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Sensor_Out4); 
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println(Sensor_Out5);
  delay(1000); 

}
```

Comment: This is not VB.Net, nor VBA - please correct the tags.

Comment: @OneFineDay i am getting data from arduino serially. My question is how to parse and displayed on Visual basic 2010. So kept tag vba

Comment: What is the purpose of the code you supplied?

Comment: @OneFineDay my above code is to understand arduino output.Then what is tag line for Visual basic[abbrevations](http://www.abbreviations.com/VBA)

Comment: Use a 3rd party library. http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

To parse a `Comma Separated Value`, aka `CSV`, you can use the `Split` method.

```
Dim csvValues As String = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
Dim arrayOfValues() As String = csvValues.Split(","c)
'c after the final quote forces the string to a char datatype
```

Comment: Splitting by comma is NOT how you should parse a CSV file.

Comment: @Neolisk- Sure their are more complicated ways for a file, but this is not a file, its data.

Comment: You should clearly state the purpose of your code then. To parse a string, where values are separated by a comma, you can use `Split(","c)`. [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), however, is a standard, for which there exist 3rd party parsers. You can write your own, but it's much more complex than 1 line of code. If it was so simple, those 3rd party parsers would not exist. Things not accounted for by a simple comma split are commas and newlines present inside the values. (In most cases comma means column split, and newline means line split.)